# How to include bower component (getmdl) js into ember?

Tags: ember.js, bower, ember-cli, material-design-lite

I install [material-design-lite](http://getmdl.io) via bower ..

So I include into my app ..

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: ['bower_components/material-design-lite/src']
    }
  });

  app.import('bower_components/material-design-lite/material.js');
```

And import into my style ..

```
@import "_color-definitions";

$color-primary: $palette-blue-500;
$color-accent: $palette-orange-400;

@import "material-design-lite";
```

The style is loaded correctly, but components that rely on javascript do not work as is the case of tabs and menus

I try to change tab clicking and nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. But ember.js builds the DOM **after** the material design lite component has been initialized. So it cannot find any DOM elements to initialize.

While looking at the source code of material design lite, I noticed that you can use the function

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

to (re-)initialize all components, and

```
componentHandler.upgradeElement(yourElement);
// or
componentHandler.upgradeElements(yourElementList);
```

to (re-)initialize specific components.

To integrate this into ember.js you could wrap up your navigation and buttons in components and initialize them via the `didInsertElement` hook:

```
// file: components/my-navigation/component.js
/* global componentHandler */
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
      componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.$()[0]);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay what if I have mdl elements in my application.hbs?